# create and share .txt file TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, text-files

I am trying to generate a .txt file based on data from a list. Number of items (rows) is at least 10.000.
The problem is not within the file itself since the file is generated and saved on external storage, and i can RUD on it and share it through share intent, e.g. by Gmail.

File size for 7000 items is aprox 70 KB, but the problem is in data parcel size 4818144 bytes, aprox 5 MB?

Lolipop and Marshmallow don't have any problems with sharing the file trough intent, but Nougat crashes with **FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION (parcel size = 4818133) JavaBinder TransactionTooLarge Exception**

**Crash** happens after I make selection in app picker, so it launches Gmail but at the moment Gmail comes in focus -> app crashes with mentioned exception, *but the file is in attachment and it is valid (gmail stays in focus and I can send the file*.

```
String FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + Constants.INSTANCE.getInventoryFilePath();

private void generateFileTxt(String fileName) {

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
        mCanWrite = true;

    if (!mCanWrite) {

        showDialogWritingError();
        this.dismiss();

    } else {

        String[] data = new String[mProductsList.size()];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String code, count;
        String newLine = "\n";
        String separator = ";";

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {

                if (mList.get(i).getCode() != null) {

                    code = mList.get(i).getCode();
                    count = String.valueOf(mCountList.get(i));

                    sb.append(code).append(separator).append(count).append(newLine);

                    String row = sb.toString();
                    data[i] = row;
                    sb.setLength(0);

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }

        try {

            File dir = new File(FILE_PATH);
            dir.mkdir();

            File file = new File(dir + "/" + fileName + mTxtExtension);
            file.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(streamOut);

            for (String row : data) streamWriter.append(row);

            streamWriter.flush();
            streamOut.flush();
            streamWriter.close();
            streamOut.close();

            showDialogShareTxt(fileName + mTxtExtension);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Method that launches share intent after file is generated:

```
private void showDialogShareTxt(String fileName) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toast_file_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    File file = new File(FILE_PATH + "/" + fileName);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending: " + fileName));

}
```

I (think) I'm sending a filename (reference, path) in intent, so why is parcel size 5MB? (I know limit is 1MB, or 512KB not sure about that but this is way too much)

**Edit 1:** stack trace

```
01-25 14:23:26.883 E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 4818144)
01-25 14:23:26.884 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-25 14:23:26.884 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: hr.vestok.inventorymanagement, PID: 26876
                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4818144 bytes
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3850)
                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                                      Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4818144 bytes
                                         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:620)
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3679)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3842)
                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342) 
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770) 
01-25 14:23:26.892 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4818144 bytes
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3850)
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                                         Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4818144 bytes
                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:620)
                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3679)
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3842)
                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342) 
                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770) 
01-25 14:23:26.897 D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, timestamp=1516886606893, fatal=1}]
01-25 14:23:27.166 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26876 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the full stack trace associated with the crash. Also, please do not use a wildcard MIME type in an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. It is your data. You know what the data format is. Use the MIME type associated with that data format.

Comment: Usually, I associate `activityStopped()` versions of this exception with the saved instance state `Bundle`. Do not put anything large into this `Bundle` yourself, and be a bit careful with widgets (e.g., an `EditText` with a few hundred KB of text).

Comment: This should be an answer. I was trying to share the contents of a log file. First, I added an `EditText`, thinking it would be easier to just copy the text. I was wrong, it was too much text. Then I tried sharing the file. Apparently, failed because the `EditText` contained all that text. When I removed the associated `Activity` and kept just the sharing, it worked as intended. Thanks!